# Show that $\phi$ is a well-defined epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let a, b, c be integers such that a divides b and b divides c.  Then $c\mathbb{Z} \subset b\mathbb{Z} \subset a\mathbb{Z}$. Let $\phi :a\mathbb{Z} / c\mathbb{Z} \to a\mathbb{Z} / b\mathbb{Z}$ can be defined by $\phi \left(at + c\mathbb{Z}\right) = at + b\mathbb{Z}$.

a) Show that $\phi$ is a well-defined epimorphism

b) What is $ker(\phi)$?

I know that to be well-defined $g=h$ must imply that $\phi (g) = \phi (h)$.

I've worked mostly on the homomorphism part, where $\phi(ab)$ must equal $\phi(a)\phi(b)$.  So I let $a_1 t_1 + c\mathbb{Z}, a_2 t_2 + c\mathbb{Z} \in a\mathbb{Z} / c\mathbb{Z}$.  Then $\phi [(a_1 t_1 + c\mathbb{Z})(a_2 t_2 + c\mathbb{Z})] = \phi(a_1a_2t_1t_2 + a_1b_1c\mathbb{Z} + a_2b_2c\mathbb{Z} + c\mathbb{Z})$.

I'm not convinced that algebraic manipulation is the best way to prove this, but I didn't know how else to start.

For part b) I have a theorem that states if $N$ is normal in $G$, then there is a homomorphism $\psi$ of $G$ on $G/N$ such that $Ker \psi = N$.  That seems like it will be useful if I can prove normality.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck? Add that to your question (not in a comment).

Comment: Also, let us know what you know about factor groups. Know any theorems about them that might be useful?

Answer (score 1):

$\phi$ is *well-defined* if the outcome of $\phi$ does not depend on the presentation of the argument of $\phi$.

So it must be checked whether we have: $$x+c\mathbb Z=y+c\mathbb Z\implies x+b\mathbb Z=y+b\mathbb Z$$or equivalently

$$c\mid x-y\implies b\mid x-y$$
This can happily be recognized as a direct consequence of $b\mid c$.

In this context $\phi$ is a homomorphism if: $$\phi((x+c\mathbb Z)+(y+c\mathbb Z))=\phi(x+c\mathbb Z)+\phi(y+c\mathbb Z)$$

This follows immediately if we work out both sides.

$\phi$ will moreover be and epimorphism if it is surjective.

This follows directly from its definition:$$\phi(x+c\mathbb Z)=x+b\mathbb Z$$

$x+c\mathbb Z$ is an element of the kernel of $\phi$ if it is sent to the zero element of $a\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$, i.e. if we have:$$\phi(x+c\mathbb Z)=x+b\mathbb Z=b\mathbb Z$$ or equivalently if: $$b\mid x$$
or equivalently if:$$x+c\mathbb Z\in b\mathbb Z/c\mathbb Z$$

So $b\mathbb Z/c\mathbb Z$ can be recognized as the kernel of $\phi$.

Comment: This is so helpful!  I understand your explanation of being well-defined.  Right now I am struggling on how to work out the left hand side of showing $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: I think that it would be $\psi ((x+c\mathbb{Z} )+ (y + c\mathbb{Z})) = \psi ((x + y + c\mathbb{Z} ) = x + y + c\mathbb{Z}$.  Is there such a thing as $2c\mathbb{Z}$? or does that just become $c\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am also confused at how surjectiveness follows directly from the definition.

Comment: LHS: $\phi((x+c\mathbb Z)+(y+c\mathbb Z))=\phi(x+y+c\mathbb Z)=x+y+b\mathbb Z. RHS: \phi(x+c\mathbb Z)+\phi(y+c\mathbb Z)=(x+b\mathbb Z)+(y+b\mathbb Z)=x+y+b\mathbb Z$. Surjectivity: let $u\in a\mathbb Z/b\mathbb Z$ then for some $x\in\mathbb Z$ we have: $u=x+b\mathbb Z=\phi(x+c\mathbb Z)$.